# MongoDB sh.status() and db.getShardDistribution() results not consistent about shards

Tags: mongodb, sharding

When I run `sh.status()` on my MongoDB server, it shows that the collections are sharded, that there are 3 shards and identifies the primary shard in each database.

When I run `db.getCollection('ReportRow').getShardDistribution()`, it returns
`Collection reporting.ReportRow is not sharded`, even though sh.status shows that it is.

Any ideas on why MongoDb would have this discrepancy?

Comment: This question really belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com) which is the site to use for database administration and configuration questions. StackOverflow is for programming topics only, of which this question is not. **Please move your question to the correct site by deleting and reposting.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shard instances exist but the data is not being sharded.

Check to insure the shard key exists on the collection as an index:
 - db.collection.getIndexes()